# Get empty json object from axis2MessageContext handleRequest method WSO AM

Tags: java, json, wso2, wso2-api-manager, interceptor

I want to get parameters from JSON body request that I wrote in my custom handler java class integrated in WSO2 AM (that intercepts all API calls published on WSO2 and send object request data to backend service). All I get is empty object. I tried with these two methods:

1)

```
    org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext axis2MessageContext = ((Axis2MessageContext) 
    messageContext).getAxis2MessageContext();
    RelayUtils.buildMessage(axis2MessageContext);

    SOAPEnvelope env = axis2MessageContext.getEnvelope();
        if (env != null) {
        SOAPBody soapbody = env.getBody(); 
        log.debug("soapbody " + soapbody); 
        }
```

2)

```
    JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject(JsonUtil.jsonPayloadToString(axis2MessageContext));
    log.debug("jsonBody " + jsonBody);

    String jsonPayloadToString = JsonUtil.jsonPayloadToString(((Axis2MessageContext) 
    messageContext).getAxis2MessageContext()); 
    log.debug("jsonPayloadToString " + jsonPayloadToString);
```

The result 1):

```
soapbody <soapenv:Body xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"/>
```

The result 2):

```
jsonBody {}, jsonPayloadToString {}
```

Any help would be great.